# How do I add a language to my path using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran, include-path

I recently downloaded Visual Studio Code so I can use it as a Fortran compiler. To do this, I installed the '[Modern Fortran](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krvajalm.linter-gfortran)' Package.

In order for this package to work, I need to add it to path.

I'm not too familiar with Visual Studio Code, so I'm not sure how to do this.
I've tried researching on the Visual Code website but couldn't find anything.
I also tried implementing the code the author included, but I couldn't get that to work either:

```
{
"fortran.includePaths": [
    "/usr/local/include",
     "/usr/local"
] }
```

If anyone more experienced with this program could offer their assistance, I'd appreciate it.
Or if they know of a better compiler for Fortran, please let me know as well.
I've been having trouble the past few days finding one that works, and this one seems the most promising.

Thanks.

Comment: `By default the gfortran executable is assumed to be found in the path.` means the path of the OS, that means edit your `~/.bashrc` or similar file

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do I edit my '~/ .bashrc' ? Is it a line of code that I must type?

Comment: It is a file in you HOME directory. You can use any editor, e.g. vscode, nano, etc. Try a search such as `bashrc PATH variable` and you will find plenty of material on the internet.